# Skip and take all?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In eloquent, how can I skip 10 rows and then get the rest of the table?

```
User::skip(10)->all();
```

The above does not work, but it gives you an idea what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$count = User::count();
$skip = 10;

User::skip($skip)->take($count - $skip)->get();
```

With one query:

```
User::skip($skip)->take(18446744073709551615)->get();
```

It's ugly, but it's an example [from official MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#id4651990):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
> ```

Comment: And if you want array, then continue with all: `User::skip(10)->get()->all();`

Comment: Thanks but this gives an error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '10' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` offset 10). Database is working as User::all() works fine.

Comment: Thanks, anyway to do this without 2 x queries?

Comment: Well, you can try something like `->take(18446744073709551615)`, it's an ugly solution, but it's from official MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#id4651990

Answer (score 2):

try something like this it work for sure..

```
$temp = User::count();
$count = $temp - 10;

$data = User::take($count)->skip(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5 returns Eloquent result as Collection.
So you can use collenction function **slice()**;

```
$users = User::get();
$slicedUsers = $users->slice(10);
```

Comment: It will work, but it can easily kill memory if you do this with big table.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yah, thats true. But for some people, can be also this solution good. If they dont work with big tables.

Comment: @Autista_z It will retrieve all data first 10 will be removed, instead of that there is trick of retriving like this as AlexeyMezenin answered.