# Laravel : pagination with limit and page number on API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a query where can i get all the data from related tables and get total `10 rows`.Now i want to set pagination parameter  in my query. if my `pagenumber=1` and `limit=2` it returns `1 and 2 rows` data with `page=1` and `limit=2`, If I am sending `page-3` and `limit-2` it returns `5 and 6 rows` and `page-3`.if `page=null` and `limit=null` return all data.

How can I do this.

My Function :

```
Post::with(['product.categories.attributes'])->whereStatus("Active")->get();
```

Also how can i pass this in `POSTMAN`

Answer (score 3):

All you need is skip / take

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Your code would be something like:

```
public function show(Request $request) {
    $perPage = $request->perpage;

    if ($request->page == "") {
        $skip = 0;
    else {
        $skip = $perPage * $request->page;
    }

    $result = Post::with(['product.categories.attributes'])
        ->skip($skip)
        ->take($perPage)
        ->where("Status", "Active")
        ->get();
}
```

Case when $_POST['perpage'] is not set can be explored here:

[Skip and take all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915099/skip-and-take-all?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Also answer about POSTMAN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137768/how-to-use-postman-for-laravel-post-request?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Is this answer what you were looking for or did I miss something?